# "NumbaPerformanceWarning: '@' is faster on contiguous arrays" warning on `@jitclass` methods

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Consider the following program which creates a `Rotator` class that stores a rotation matrix `_R` and can `rotate` a vector `v`:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
import numba as nb
from numba.experimental import jitclass

@jitclass([("_R", nb.float64[:,:])])
class Rotator:
    _R : npt.NDArray[np.float64]
    def __init__(self, R : npt.NDArray[np.float64]):
        self._R = R

    def rotate(self, v : npt.NDArray[np.float64]) -> npt.NDArray[np.float64]:
        return self._R @ v

R = np.eye(3)
print(R.flags)
rotator = Rotator(R)
rotator.rotate(np.array([1., 0., 0.]))
```

Here are `R`'s flags that get printed :

```
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
```

It's clear that `R` is row-major contiguous, but Numba complains that it's not :

```
<string>:3: NumbaPerformanceWarning: '@' is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (Array(float64, 2, 'A', False, aligned=True), Array(float64, 1, 'C', False, aligned=True))
```

However the same function works without warning if it's pulled out of a class.

```
@njit
def rotate(R : npt.NDArray[np.float64], v : npt.NDArray[np.float64]) -> npt.NDArray[np.float64]:
    return R @ v

rotate(np.eye(3), np.array([1., 0., 0.]))
```

I would appreciate any explanation on why the contiguity of the array changes according  to Numba when compiled as a class member.

Thank you!

EDIT : Tried Jérôme's suggestion from the comment and tried declaring `R_` as a row major 2D array (C-style).

```py
@jitclass([("_R", nb.float64[::1,:])])
```

but I now get the error

```
<string>:3: NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning: Code using Numba extension API maybe depending on 'old_style' error-capturing, which is deprecated and will be replaced by 'new_style' in a future release. See details at https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-old-style-numba-captured-errors
Exception origin:
  File "/Users/xx/miniconda3/envs/xx/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/np/arrayobj.py", line 6397, in array_to_array
    assert fromty.mutable != toty.mutable or toty.layout == 'A'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    rotator = Rotator(R)
  File "/Users/xx/miniconda3/envs/xx/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/experimental/jitclass/base.py", line 124, in __call__
    return cls._ctor(*bind.args[1:], **bind.kwargs)
  File "/Users/xx/miniconda3/envs/xx/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/Users/xx/miniconda3/envs/xx/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Internal error at <numba.core.typeinfer.CallConstraint object at 0x11edbbbe0>.
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)

Enable logging at debug level for details.

File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Comment: `nb.float64[:,:]` means that the array is not guaranteed to be contiguous. It may neither be row-major nor column major. You need to use `::1` to specify an axis is contiguous (only the one with a stride=1). In the second case, there is no Numba type information (only CPython ones which are generally useless for JITs, like PyPy or Numba, because the type system are incompatible and the later is optional). Thus, Numba deduce the type. I think Numba does not check the array is actually contiguous or not at runtime so the warning may not relate to an actual issue.

Comment: @JeromeRichard thank you! I have edited the question with my attempt at specifying the contiguity, but I'm getting another error.

Comment: I now see that specifying `nb.float64[:,::1])` instead of `nb.float64[::1,:])` resolves the issue but I find the syntax misleading. The first index is usually the "row" index so I would expect C-contiguity to be specified with the former.

Comment: For row-major 2D arrays, like in C, you need `nb.float64[:,::1]`, *not* `nb.float64[::1,:]` (which is column-major, like in FORTRAN). The error reported by Numba seems that it does not (fully) support yet column-major array (which is not really a problem here finally).

Comment: In C, the last dimension is the most contiguous one so it makes sense it is the last one here too. The Numpy conversion for matrices is the international one : `Matrix_{row,column}`. In C, we would write `float M[rows][columns];` and access items with `M[row][column]` (and each row is stored contiguously).

Comment: I meant to ask - if in C "rows" are packed together (row major order), then isn't the first dimension the most contiguous? How is contiguity defined in this context?

Comment: Technically, yes, rows are packed contiguously, so it would makes sense to write `nb.float64[::1,::1]`, but AFAIK only one dimension can be marked as contiguous. In fact, knowing that rows are packed contiguously is not very important for performance (though it help a bit). Indeed, `M[i][j]` and `M[i+1][j]` are not contiguously stored while `M[i][j]` and `M[i][j+1]` are. We can defined the contiguous dimension as the one having a stride of `M.itemsize` (that is `sizeof(M[0][0])` in C).

Comment: Note knowing some items are stored contiguously help the compiler to generate an assembly code that benefit from using SIMD instructions. This is critical for performance. It also avoid some multiplication when accessing items along the contiguous dimension.